# Problems with translating c++ to javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I was trying to replicate this c++ code in javascript.
https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/OneLoneCoder_PathFinding_AStar.cpp

The code should draw a yellow line from the red point to the green point.

I checked my implementation multiple times but I still can't figure out why it is not working.

For some reason it won't set the parent for my objects correctly.

Which results in the path not getting drawn.

Could really need some help here.

```js
width = 11;
height = 9;

s = 50;

c = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(c);
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = width * s;
c.height = height * s;

nodes = [];

for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  row = [];
  nodes.push(row);
  for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    row.push(new Node(x, y));
  }

}

SetNeighbours();

function SetNeighbours() {
  for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      if (x > 0) {
        nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x - 1][y])
      }
      if (x < width - 1) {
        nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x + 1][y])
      }
      if (y > 0) {
        nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x][y - 1])
      }
      if (y < height - 1) {
        nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x][y + 1])
      }
    }

  }
}

nodes[3][0].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][1].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][2].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][3].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][4].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][5].obstacle = true;


nodes[7][3].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][4].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][5].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][6].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][7].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][8].obstacle = true;

start = nodes[1][1];
end = nodes[9][7];

//end.parent = nodes[9][6];
//nodes[9][6].parent = nodes[9][5]

current = start;
start.localGlobal = 0;
start.globalGoal = heuristic(start, end);

notTested = [];
notTested.push(start);

while (notTested.length > 0 && current != end) {

  notTested.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.globalGoal < b.globalGoal
  });
  while (notTested.length > 0 && notTested[0].visited) {
    notTested.shift();
  }

  if (notTested.length == 0) {
    break;
  }

  current = notTested[0];
  current.visited = true;

  for (let n of current.neighbours) {
    if (!n.visited && !n.obstacle) {
      notTested.push(n);
    }

    newGoal = current.localGoal + distance(current, n);

    if (newGoal < n.localGoal) {
      n.parent = current;
      n.localGoal = newGoal;
      n.globalGoal = n.localGoal + heurisitc(n, end);
    }

  }
}

DrawCanvas();

function DrawCanvas() {

  for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let node of nodes[x][y].neighbours) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x * s + (s / 2), y * s + (s / 2));
        ctx.lineTo(node.x * s + (s / 2), node.y * s + (s / 2));
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "navy";
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }

  for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      if (nodes[x][y] == start) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "crimson";
      } else if (nodes[x][y] == end) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      } else if (nodes[x][y].visited) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      } else if (nodes[x][y].obstacle) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
      } else {
        //ctx.fillStyle = x % 2 != y % 2 ? "lightgrey" : "darkgrey";
        ctx.fillStyle = "navy";
      }
      ctx.fillRect(x * s + 5, y * s + 5, s - 10, s - 10);

    }
  }
}

if (end != null) {
  p = end;
  while (p.parent != null) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p.x * s + (s / 2), p.y * s + (s / 2));
    ctx.lineTo(p.parent.x * s + (s / 2), p.parent.y * s + (s / 2));
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.stroke();
    p = p.parent;
  }
}


function Node(x, y) {
  this.obstacle = false;
  this.visited = false;
  this.globalGoal = 1000000;
  this.localGoal = 1000000;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.neighbours = [];
  this.parent = null;
}

function distance(a, b) {
  return Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x) ** 2 + (b.y - a.y) ** 2)
}

function heuristic(a, b) {
  return distance(a, b);
}
```

```css
body
{
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Be careful when directly translating c++ into JS. They're not 100% alike. None of the variables have a declaration and I think they're all global. Also `this` in JS doesn't act like c++

Comment: *I checked my implementation multiple times* --  You probably can't see the error because you do not know JavaScript well enough and you are looking at your program through a C++ lens.  Do not use C++ as a model in writing Javascript code.  Learn JavaScript proper, and implement whatever you are trying to implement without any prior knowledge of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line where you set `current` variable you have a typo
There should be `start.localGoal = 0;` and not `start.localGlobal = 0;`

```js
width = 11;
height = 9;

s = 50;

c = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(c);
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = width * s;
c.height = height * s;

nodes = [];

for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    nodes[x] = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        nodes[x].push(new Node(x, y));
    }
}

SetNeighbours();

function SetNeighbours() {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (x > 0) {
                nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x - 1][y])
            }
            if (x < width - 1) {
                nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x + 1][y])
            }
            if (y > 0) {
                nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x][y - 1])
            }
            if (y < height - 1) {
                nodes[x][y].neighbours.push(nodes[x][y + 1])
            }
        }

    }
}

nodes[3][0].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][1].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][2].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][3].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][4].obstacle = true;
nodes[3][5].obstacle = true;


nodes[7][3].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][4].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][5].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][6].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][7].obstacle = true;
nodes[7][8].obstacle = true;

start = nodes[1][1];
end = nodes[9][7];

//end.parent = nodes[9][6];
//nodes[9][6].parent = nodes[9][5]

start.localGoal = 0;
start.globalGoal = heuristic(start, end);
current = start;

notTested = [];
notTested.push(start);

while (notTested.length > 0 && current !== end) {

    notTested.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.globalGoal < b.globalGoal
    });
    while (notTested.length > 0 && notTested[0].visited) {
        notTested.shift();
    }

    if (notTested.length === 0) {
        break;
    }

    const current = notTested[0];
    current.visited = true;

    for (let n of current.neighbours) {
        if (!n.visited && !n.obstacle) {
            notTested.push(n);
        }

        const newGoal = current.localGoal + distance(current, n);

        if (newGoal < n.localGoal) {
            n.parent = current;
            n.localGoal = newGoal;
            n.globalGoal = n.localGoal + heuristic(n, end);
        }

    }
}

DrawCanvas();

function DrawCanvas() {

    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (let node of nodes[x][y].neighbours) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x * s + (s / 2), y * s + (s / 2));
                ctx.lineTo(node.x * s + (s / 2), node.y * s + (s / 2));
                ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "navy";
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (nodes[x][y] === start) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "crimson";
            } else if (nodes[x][y] === end) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            } else if (nodes[x][y].visited) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            } else if (nodes[x][y].obstacle) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
            } else {
                //ctx.fillStyle = x % 2 != y % 2 ? "lightgrey" : "darkgrey";
                ctx.fillStyle = "navy";
            }
            ctx.fillRect(x * s + 5, y * s + 5, s - 10, s - 10);

        }
    }
}

if (end != null) {
    p = end;
    while (p.parent != null) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x * s + (s / 2), p.y * s + (s / 2));
        ctx.lineTo(p.parent.x * s + (s / 2), p.parent.y * s + (s / 2));
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.stroke();
        p = p.parent;
    }
}


function Node(x, y) {
    this.obstacle = false;
    this.visited = false;
    this.globalGoal = 1000000;
    this.localGoal = 1000000;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.neighbours = [];
    this.parent = null;
}

function distance(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((b.x - a.x) ** 2 + (b.y - a.y) ** 2);
}

function heuristic(a, b) {
    return distance(a, b);
}
```

```css
body
{
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: I thought that the A* algorithm would find the shortest path. Not sure what went wrong there.